# Sql connection and GUI problem

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

In my code I connect MySql database and query data.
I draw graphics scene using this data.

When database connection return false,
my program try to connect database with `( db.Open())`.

In the meantime, gui is locked.
Do you have any idea about this problem?
How can I solve it?

Comment: not even close to enough information to help you.

Comment: Can you explain a background thread?

Comment: @joni: I agree, but can a mysql-connection in c++ shared in multiple threads? I'm asking this because in C# it can not be shared, so he'd also need to draw the graphics in the background-thread or pass the data around.

Comment: @Bobby that matters on the Library you are using to connect to MySql. Often, you find a clue in the corresponding docu ("...provides thread-safe access...")

Comment: Keep in mind that you only need to use `db.Open()` once during the lifetime of the program. If the normal queries are still to slow then you will need to put all of your sql communication in a separate thread

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you'll have to create a multi-threaded application. A process can have multiple threads which are something like sub-processes that run parallel to the main-sub-process (Slam me for this explanation :P). Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) for further information about threads.

In your case, you'll have to spawn a thread which, in the background, makes the MySql connection ([QT Doc](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/threads-modules.html) says "A connection can only be used from within the thread that created it."), fetches the data from the server and draws it to the widget you want. In the time the background thread is doing this, the main run cycle of you application will not get disrupted, and your app will not get unresponsive. However, you'll have to implement a mechanism that ensures that only 1 Mysql-Data-Fetcher-Thread exists at a time, because else it will get chaotic (e.g. multiple threads want access to the same drawing region, which is impossible in QT).

On the QT documentation site exists a very good [section about threads](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads.html) and how to implement them in QT. You should also consult the external links there if you're new to thread programming.